# Can not import correctly Seaborn into my IBM Watson-Studio

Tags: anaconda, ibm-cloud, seaborn, conda, watson-studio

I am trying to import seaborn in my IBM cloud (watson) on windows for my final assignment, but somehow it gives me an error. I am trying the following code to import seaborn:

```
#notice: installing seaborn might takes a few minutes\
!conda install -c anaconda seaborn -y
```

But then happens this: Please I need help to solve the issue

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: done

 Package Plan

  environment location: /opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main

  added / updated specs:
    - seaborn


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    argon2-cffi-20.1.0         |   py37h7b6447c_1          49 KB  anaconda
    defusedxml-0.6.0           |             py_0          23 KB  anaconda
    entrypoints-0.3            |           py37_0          12 KB  anaconda
    fontconfig-2.13.0          |       h9420a91_0         291 KB  anaconda
    icu-58.2                   |       he6710b0_3        22.7 MB  anaconda
    jupyter_client-6.1.7       |             py_0          76 KB  anaconda
    libpng-1.6.37              |       hbc83047_0         364 KB  anaconda
    libtiff-4.1.0              |       h2733197_1         607 KB  anaconda
    libuuid-1.0.3              |       h1bed415_2          16 KB  anaconda
    libxcb-1.14                |       h7b6447c_0         610 KB  anaconda
    libxml2-2.9.10             |       hb55368b_3         1.3 MB  anaconda
    lz4-c-1.9.2                |       heb0550a_3         203 KB  anaconda
    markupsafe-1.1.1           |   py37h14c3975_1          26 KB  anaconda
    mistune-0.8.4              |py37h14c3975_1001          53 KB  anaconda
    ncurses-6.2                |       he6710b0_1         1.1 MB  anaconda
    packaging-20.4             |             py_0          35 KB  anaconda
    pandocfilters-1.4.2        |           py37_1          13 KB  anaconda
    pyjwt-1.7.1                |           py37_0          32 KB  anaconda
    pyparsing-2.4.7            |             py_0          64 KB  anaconda
    webencodings-0.5.1         |           py37_1          19 KB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        27.5 MB
Downloading and Extracting Packages
libxml2-2.9.10       | 1.3 MB    | ###############################6      |  86% WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140): Could not remove or rename /opt/conda/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.10-hb55368b_3/bin/xmllint.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140): Could not remove or rename /opt/conda/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.10-hb55368b_3/bin/xml2-config.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140): Could not remove or rename /opt/conda/pkgs/libx
```

Comment: Edit your question to clarify that it (likely) is IBM Watson Studio, if it is a notebook environment, which runtime. Tag your question with watson-studio

Comment: Yes it is IBM Watson Studio

Answer (score 1):

If you the notebook is created using the default runtime as shown below, then Seaborn is installed by default.

Run the below command to see `Seaborn` in the list of packages installed.

```
!pip list
```

[image]

[image]

If you don't see Seaborn in the list, try installing with the below command

```
!pip install seaborn
```

If you still see the error, update your question with the region in which you have your project with notebook created and also screenshots of the environment + error helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! It works with: !pip install seaborn

Comment: Happy to help. Can you mark the above as answer